# How Upload File To Buffer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file. However, much of the material I find on the Internet explains how to save the file to a folder on the server, but for my solution I just needed to buffer. Is it possible? I upload the file to the server buffer, then read and clean.

Obs.: I am using telerik components, and need to read / import an Excel file.

Thanks

Comment: i dont think so putting in buffer is a good option

Comment: They are small files, and throws them into a folder I see that is not the best solution. But, what is your opinion? @anishMarokey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you use a binary stream, the approach to buffer it regardless of the context of execution (asp.net vs winforms or whatever) is pretty common:

```
public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
  byte[] buffer;
  FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  try
  {
     int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
     buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
     int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
     int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

    // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
    while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
       sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
    }
  finally
  {
    fileStream.Close();
  }
   return buffer;
 }
```

Also, check out this:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Answer (score 0):

The default FileUpload component presents you the file as a `Byte[]` - you could just wrap it in a `MemoryStream`:

```
var strm = new MemoryStream(fileUpload.PostedFile.Contents);
  // I think its PostedFile.Contents, something like that anyway
```